# One formula to combine 2 lists (2021)

Tags: excel-formula

I have one list starting from `B1` (`=UNIQUE(A1:A8)`), and another list starting from `D1` (`=UNIQUE(C1:C8)`). Thus `=B1#` and `=D1#` in other cells both spill.

[image]

Now, I would like to know if we could find one formula to combine List `B1#` and List `D1#` (extract only unique values) by dynamic array functions, LAMBDA, LET, etc.

I don't want to move the position of the two lists. Does anyone have any good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not be following what you want the shape to be, but here are two shapes:

**Side-by-Side**

```
=CHOOSE({1,2},B1#,D1#)
```

If you want it to take the original A and C columns as input and do all the work, then:

```
=CHOOSE({1,2},UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,NOT(ISBLANK(A:A)))),UNIQUE(FILTER(C:C,NOT(ISBLANK(C:C)))))
```

or a LET version of the same which does not require retyping the inputs:

```
=LET( Ltrs, A:A,
      Nmbrs, C:C,
       CHOOSE( {1,2},
                UNIQUE(FILTER(Ltrs,NOT(ISBLANK(Ltrs)))),
                UNIQUE(FILTER(Nmbrs,NOT(ISBLANK(Nmbrs)))) ) )
```

**End-on-End**

```
=LET( uLtrs, B1#,
      uNmbrs, D1#,
       ltrCt, ROWS(uLtrs),
       idx, SEQUENCE( ltrCt + ROWS(uNmbrs) ),
       IF( idx <= ltrCt, uLtrs, INDEX( uNmbrs, idx-ltrCt ) ) )
```

Similar as above, if you want it to take the original A and C columns as input and do all the work, then:

```
=LET( Ltrs, A:A,
      Nmbrs, C:C,
       uLtrs, UNIQUE(FILTER(Ltrs,NOT(ISBLANK(Ltrs)))),
       uNmbrs, UNIQUE(FILTER(Nmbrs,NOT(ISBLANK(Nmbrs)))),
       ltrCt, ROWS(uLtrs),
       idx, SEQUENCE( ltrCt + ROWS(uNmbrs) ),
       IF( idx <= ltrCt, uLtrs, INDEX( uNmbrs, idx-ltrCt ) ) )
```

Both spill the results.
[image: results]

Answer (score 1):

Place the following code into cell F2 and drag formula downwards to F14. This will give you a unique list of both Column A and Column D

```
=IF(IFERROR(IF(INDEX($A$1:$A$99999,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$A$1:$A$99999),0))=0,NA(),INDEX($A$1:$A$99999,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$A$1:$A$99999),0))),INDEX($C$1:$C$99999,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$C$1:$C$99999),0)))=0,NA(),IFERROR(IF(INDEX($A$1:$A$99999,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$A$1:$A$99999),0))=0,NA(),INDEX($A$1:$A$99999,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$A$1:$A$99999),0))),INDEX($C$1:$C$99999,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$C$1:$C$99999),0))))
```

Let me know if you need it to behave differently.